# How can I control whether a long or short citation is printed?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa6

I'm using the `APA6`class to write an article. When citing articles, more names are written out the first time I cite an entry compared to the second time I cite it.

This is fine, but sometimes I want to have control over which version (the longer or the shorter) gets printed (one use case could be that I want to create a table where the long form takes up too much space or that I want to list some articles and have their formatting look the same). How can I achieve this? (I'd rather not manipulate the APA6 class itself since I would like this solution to be portable).

MWE for demonstation:

```
\documentclass[biblatex]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a test. The best test ever was actually written by \cite{Testson2019}. I repeat: It was written by \cite{Testson2019}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where my `References.bib` file looks like this:

```
@article{Testson2019,
    Author = {Test Testson AND Trying Tryingson AND Latex Latexson AND Stack Exchangeson},
    Journal = {Journal of Silly Articles},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {1-10},
    Title = {This is a silly journal article},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2019}}
```

generates

> This is a test. The best test ever was actually written by Testson,
>   Tryingson, Latexson, and Exchangeson, 2019. I repeat: It was written
>   by Testson et al., 2019.

As can be seen, the second time `Testson2019` is referenced, "et al." is used rather than printing all four surnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` checks with `\ifciteseen` if the citation should appear in long or short form. You can manipulate its decision by redefining that test at the beginning of a citation.

You can pack that up into two commands that you can issue before a `\cite` to change its behaviour.

```
\documentclass[biblatex]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ForceNextCiteShort}{\AtNextCite{\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}}
\newcommand*{\ForceNextCiteLong}{\AtNextCite{\let\ifciteseen\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a test. The best test ever was actually written by \cite{yoon}.

I repeat: It was written by \cite{yoon}.

\ForceNextCiteLong\cite{yoon}

I repeat: It was written by \cite{yoon}.

\ForceNextCiteShort\cite{cotton}

\cite{cotton}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a test. The best test ever was actually written by Yoon, Ryu, Kim, and Ahn, 2006.//I repeat: It was written by Yoon et al., 2006.//Yoon, Ryu, Kim, and Ahn, 2006//I repeat: It was written by Yoon et al., 2006.//Cotton et al., 1999//Cotton et al., 1999]

Those `\cite`s are still being tracked as normal, though. So in the MWE the second `cotton` citation is short even though there has been no long citation of that work. If you want your forced citation not to influence the general long/short behaviour you need a slightly more involved definition

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ForceNextCiteShort}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \blx@opt@citetracker@false
    \protected\long\def\blx@imc@ifentryseen##1##2##3{##2}%
    \let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}}
\newcommand*{\ForceNextCiteLong}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \blx@opt@citetracker@false
    \protected\long\def\blx@imc@ifentryseen##1##2##3{##3}%
    \let\ifciteseen\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother
```

This means that the citation tracker just ignores this citation.